# What is the best practice in storing pinyin characters in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am storing Chinese pinyin characters into a MySQL column latin1_ci encoded. I noticed that I am losing information. I was wondering how or what is the correct way of storing pinyin characters. i.e

```
nǚ rén
```

Comment: The link above answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend utf8 for the charset, utf8_general_ci for the collation.

Comment: Just did that. Thanx. I had get my charset to latin1, did not work.